# Operation result with one of the variables null (empty) in SAS

Tags: sas

I am converting SAS code to C# code and I don't have platform to run SAS code, what I have only source code, and I have line of the code in SAS where one of the variables is empty and another is not and I would like to know what would be result of y in following operation.

```
x = .
y = 10 / x - 1;
```

x is empty (null) Please advice.

Thanks a lot in advance for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result will be missing (null in other programming languages). Any calculation with a missing value will return missing.

```
data _null_;
 x = .;
 y = 10 / x - 1;
 put y=;
run;

y=.
NOTE: Missing values were generated as a result of performing an operation on missing values.
```

Answer (score 1):

y would also be NA (.)

You might want to look into [WPS](http://teamwpc.co.uk/home) - it's an interpreter for SAS code that's substantially cheaper than SAS itself, and [it has a 30-day free trial](http://teamwpc.co.uk/tryorbuy).  It doesn't cover 100% of SAS, but you could easily use it to test out simple questions like this one.

Comment: Thanks Matt.  I will check WPS.